# Exception when using Period with PeriodType.forFields

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using joda-time to get some time/date components between two dates.
([http://joda-time.sourceforge.net](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html))

When I use PeriodTypes as `standard()` or `day()`, everything is working fine.
But when I use the `PeriodType.forFields(...)` I get an exception:

So, this works:

```
Period p = new Period(new DateTime(startDate.getTime()), new DateTime(endDate.getTime()), PeriodType.days()).normalizedStandard(PeriodType.days());
return p.getDays();
```

this throws an exception:

```
Period p = new Period(new DateTime(startDate.getTime()), new DateTime(endDate.getTime()), PeriodType.forFields(new DurationFieldType[]{DurationFieldType.months(), DurationFieldType.weeks()})).normalizedStandard(PeriodType.forFields(new DurationFieldType[]{DurationFieldType.months(), DurationFieldType.weeks()}));
return p.getMonths();
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Any help is really appreciated.

Exception:

> > 10-17 14:35:50.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):
> >     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Field is not supported 10-17
> >     14:35:50.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):   at
> >     org.joda.time.PeriodType.setIndexedField(PeriodType.java:690) 10-17
> >     14:35:50.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):   at
> >     org.joda.time.Period.withYears(Period.java:896) 10-17 14:35:50.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1350):     at
> >     org.joda.time.Period.normalizedStandard(Period.java:1630)

*Edit:*

*I'm quite sure that this is a bug. I tested some more combinations and there seems to be a problem with non standard PeriodTypes without years.
For example:*

*This works:*

```
Period p = new Period(new DateTime(startDate.getTime()), new DateTime(endDate.getTime()), PeriodType.standard()).normalizedStandard(PeriodType.standard());
return p.getMonths();
```

*If I remove the years PeriodType with* `withYearsRemoved()` *I get an exception:*

```
Period p = new Period(new DateTime(startDate.getTime()), new DateTime(endDate.getTime()), PeriodType.standard().withYearsRemoved()).normalizedStandard(PeriodType.standard().withYearsRemoved());
return p.getMonths();
```

Comment: And the exception is?

Comment: sorry, exception was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that difference between `startDate` and `endDate` is more then year, so `normalized standard` cann't be calculated.

From [Period::normalizedStandard](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#normalizedStandard%28org.joda.time.PeriodType%29)

> If the period contains years or months, then the months will be
>   normalized to be between 0 and 11. The days field and below will be
>   normalized as necessary, however this will not overflow into the
>   months field. Thus a period of 1 year 15 months will normalize to 2
>   years 3 months. But a period of 1 month 40 days will remain as 1 month
>   40 days.

So if difference is more then 1 year, you cann't use `normalizedStandard withYearsRemoved`.

**Example:**

```
  DateTime startDate = new DateTime().minusYears(10);
  DateTime endDate = new DateTime();
  Period p = new Period(startDate, endDate, PeriodType.standard().withYearsRemoved())
     .normalizedStandard(PeriodType.standard().withYearsRemoved());
  p.getMonths(); // throw exception, difference is 10 years!  

  DateTime startDate = new DateTime().minusMonths(10);
  DateTime endDate = new DateTime();
  Period p = new Period(startDate, endDate, PeriodType.standard().withYearsRemoved())
     .normalizedStandard(PeriodType.standard().withYearsRemoved());
  p.getMonths(); // return 10, difference is less then 1 year  

  DateTime startDate = new DateTime().minusYears(10);
  DateTime endDate = new DateTime();
  Period p = new Period(startDate, endDate, PeriodType.standard().withYearsRemoved());
  p.getMonths(); // return 120, standart isn't normalized
```

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed that in the class description :)